# removeFromSuperview does not "release" my UILabels

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

Because of some rendering issues with UITextViews, I am dynamically creating UILabels for each of the UITextViews in my scene, and using renderInContext to make an image. Works perfectly, except that I need to remove the labels after the render, else they will re-render next time I execute the renderInContext. I am using removeFromSuperview to try remove the labels, but they are not "releasing" they just accumulate with each render, and they do re-render in some cases. How can I get rid of the labels so they will not re-render?

```
for (i = 0; i < [labelsArray count]; i++) {

    [[labelsArray objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];

    NSLog(@"label: %@", [labelsArray objectAtIndex:i]);
```

Comment: How to you render the labels? If you're adding them to `labelsArray` they will be retained twice. I'm pretty sure `removeFromSuperview` releases your labels, but unless there are no other references to them (like being in an array) they won't be deallocated. Try logging the `superview` of your labels before and after `removeFromSuperview` to see if they are properly removed.

Comment: rendering them in a view using renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Comment: they are not removed, they are still in the array and a still rendering. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are still in your array, they are still retained. if you want them to be released, you'll have to remove your label from your array.
Try to set a UILabel pointer on it , remove it from superview and array, then display it.
It should be released

Comment: You mean like this? : for (i = 0; i < [labelsArray count]; i++) {
            UILabel *labelToDelete = (UILabel *)[labelsArray objectAtIndex: i];
            [labelToDelete removeFromSuperview];} This did not work I think.

Comment: you can use the forin loop in objective C:

    for(UILabel* labelToDelete in labelsArray){
        [labelToDelete removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [labelsArray removeAllObjects];

the last line release all UILabels retained by your array (this method is for an NSMutableArray only, assuming you are using one)

Comment: And if you are using a regular NSArray, you can call release directly on the NSArray. The implementation of NSArray will take care of sending release to all the objects stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that I not only needed to remove my subViews (labels and any deleted  UITextViews too) from superViews, but also remove these views from the arrays using:

```
[array removeObject:viewObject];
```